# Apply currency filter using angularjs and injecting $filter in function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have a function where i need to inject filter for filtering currency.
This is my directive,
module.exports = prAmountAutoCorrectingField;

```
function prAmountAutoCorrectingField($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    }

;

function link(scope, elm, attrs, ctrls) {
    if (!ctrls) return;
        ctrls.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrls.$modelValue)
        });
        ctrls.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
            elm.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
            return plainNumber;
        });
}
}
```

HTML Code

I am getting error like Error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: undefinedFilterProvider <-
>   undefinedFilter.

I need help on how to inject filter here so it should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is saying that attrs.format is undefined. So this means that you're trying to pass directly the filter's name to your directive.

I don't think that's a good idea. It would be better to hava a custom filter that take 2 parameters, the data to format and the currency.

If you want to keep the attrs.format way, link your HTML code and the controller of the view, so we can check what is wrong.

Comment: This is my directive and i am trying to inject filter in this. I need it to be like this.Here is my HTML.
<input id="pr-line-items-price-per-unit" class="form-control" type="text" required  ng-model="vm.selectedLineItem.prLineDTO.varPrice"
                ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" pr-amount-auto-correcting-field="currency"/>

Comment: so what is the attrs.format in your link function ? If you use an attrs.format this mean the input attribute should have a format="<valeur>" in. If you''re looking to get the pr-amount-auto-correcting-field then it's attrs.prAmountAutoCorrectingField. Furthermore  if you want to pass 'currency'  wirte it like this  pr-amount-auto-correcting-field={{'currency'}}

Comment: No problem, however this solution will only work if the value of the prAmountAutoCorrectingField won't change (like changing currency), Otherwise you'll want to use one way data-binding in your directive.